# XPath of non-tagged sibling

Tags: xml, xpath

For instance, what XPath would return "text one", "text two", and "text three"?

```
<root>
<item>
   <richtext>
      <par>
         <break />
         text one
         <break />
         text two
         <break />
         text three
      </par>
   </richtext>
</item>
</root>
```

The number of `<break/>` tags varies.

Answer (score 2):

> what XPath would return "text one",
>   "text two", and "text three"?

**Use**:

```
string(/*/*/*/par)
```

This evaluates to the string value of the `par` element, which is (by definition) the concatenation of all its text-node descendents.

**In case if you want to select all text nodes that a children of `par` (excluding the white-space-only text-nodes), use**:

```
/*/*/*/par/text()[normalize-space()]
```